# How to add image inside an Textview in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I have been trying to build a textview which can hold image as well. As it works in iOS using NStextAttachment and NSattributedString. Maybe somehow I have inject the image to the FormattedString . Does anyone have any idea? PLease help

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not possible for now. You can try some ways like StackLayout with horizontal orientation. So you need to work on css for same background colors and size etc...

```
<StackLayout orientation=“horizontal”>
<TextField .... />
<Image .... />
</StackLayout>
```